# He said: Muhammad said: Allah said?

Tags: quran, hadith

I keep reading numerous "He said: Muhammad said: Allah said:" quotes and narrations (hearsay) and cannot stop wondering:

Why weren't such quotes of Allah included in his book, like every other verse in the Quran?

> **6:114** "Shall I seek other than God as a judge when He has sent down to you this book
>   sufficiently detailed?" Those to whom We have given the book know it is sent down from your Lord with truth; so do not be of those who have doubt.
>   **6:115** ***The word of your Lord has been completed with truth and justice***; there is no changing His words. He is the Hearer, the Knower. **6:116** If you obey the majority of those on earth they will lead you away from God's path; that is because they follow conjecture, and that is because they only guess.

Would attributing these additional words to Allah contradict his very statement that The Quran is His **COMPLETE** word?

Answer (score 9):

The simple answer is, they're not included as verses in the Qur'an because they're not verses of the Qur'an.  Nowhere does the Qur'an claim to be a record of everything God ever said (his "**COMPLETE** word," as it were), not even if one limits the scope just to the prophet Muhammed himself.

Rather, the Qur'an says that even if you [had two entire seas full of ink](http://quran.com/18/109), they would not be enough to record the words of God.

The Qur'an in its entirety is merely a subset of the words of God, words which include at least three other named Scriptures and countless revelations to countless prophets since the beginning of mankind.

Comment: I'm specifically interested about the quotes that were supposedly "said" to Muhammed by God (ie exacly how the Quran was). Thank you.

Comment: Answer's the same: they're not included in the Qur'an because they're not part of the Qur'an.

Comment: Sorry final question for clarification purposes. Are you implying that there were revelations that were included in the Quran and some that were (for whatever reason) omitted?

Comment: I'm not "implying" anything.  I'm *outright stating* that the Qur'an is not and has never been a complete record of every revelation God ever made.

Comment: @banging there are certainly examples of abrogated verses in the Qur'an - some abrogated both in meaning and recitation, and some abrogated only in recitation.

Comment: @banging From my limited knowledge, God revealed knowledge to Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) either directly or through the help of Jibril. And some revelations are meant to be recited as a part of Quran, some are revelation when Prophet inquires about something (oh behalf of someone), therefore not included in Quran. Prophet Muhammad and other prophets are messengers of God in two senses: 1. They (not all of them) bring down/recite the scripture. 2. Their words and lives are messages in themselves.